# Nginx SSL Configuration Failing

Tags: server, nginx, ssl

I have configured SSL on my LEMP with a self-signed certificate according to the instructions here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-nginx-in-ubuntu-16-04

The ONLY exception is the `default_server` which I will not be able to use because this will be a multi-vhost server (eventually)

Nothing fails during the entire process until I attempt to browse the site via HTTPS, it fails with `Secure Connection Failed` with no other option to bypass.  (I expect an error based on the self-signed cert, but in Firefox there is usually that 'Advanced' button I can bypass with.)

I have also verified that the proper ports are open to the server via `netstat -ntlp`

[image: netstat output]

You can browse the site here if you wish to see the error message: https://www.azem.us/   (it's non-production, so I'm not real worried about it...)

Running `curl -I https://www.azem.us/` is returning me the following error: `curl: (35) gnutls_handshake() failed: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.`

What's really got me, is there is nothing in any configured error log.

What can I do to fix this, and be able to serve up these sites with SSL?

**NOTE:** This also happens with a properly SSL certificate from a real CA

**Progress Diagnosing**
Running `openssl s_client -connect www.azem.us:443` is returning me some interesting info:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=104
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 305 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1474399712
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

I am probably off in my thinking but doesnt this mean the certificates do not exist on the server?   I can verify that they do indeed exist, and are properly configured in my `nginx.conf`

And with: `openssl s_client -verify www.azem.us:443`
Returns:

```
verify depth is 0
connect: Connection refused
connect:errno=111
```

Per **nmap** from another machine

```
Host is up (0.0043s latency).
Not shown: 998 filtered ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
80/tcp  open  http
443/tcp open  https
```

`telnet` can connect, but immediately closes the connection when attempting port 443

GIT REPO to config: https://github.com/kpirnie/LEMP-Command

Finally getting somewhere...  I changed the `error_log` level for the main nginx.conf and am now getting an error in the log: `2016/09/21 08:22:58 [error] 29557#29557: *4 no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking, client: this.is.my.ip, server: 0.0.0.0:443`

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text, as it is not easy to read; instead, copy the text here and apply code formatting. Also, it looks like you have enabled HSTS and OCSP stapling. With HSTS, modern browsers will outright *refuse* to connect to a site unless it can connect properly via HTTPS, because HSTS is the site telling the browser to do so.

Comment: With curl I get back "curl: (35) Encountered end of file" w/o the insecure option. I would look again at your nginx options. Have you run `nginx -t`?

Comment: @muru, I have disabled that, and the issue still occurs.

Comment: @Jeroen yes, `nginx -t` is fine

Comment: HSTS doesn't go away by just disabling it, browsers remember that setting. Try with a different browser.

Comment: @Jeroen I am also getting fine results back from `curl -I` on http protocol from a remote to server location, https is not

Comment: The same issue still results with multiple browsers across multiple machines (of which have never been to the site), also performing a `curl -I` against the https is returning a `curl: (35) gnutls_handshake() failed: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.` Error

Comment: Try using let's encrypt, It well explained over here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04
Make sure nginx service is stopped while generating certificates.

Comment: Although I cannot use letsencrypt in production; for testing purposes I am making the attempt with nginx stopped, it fails with `cannot connect to DOMAIN`

Comment: And again, we are back to square one.  I was able to generate the cert, via having nginx running.   All known errors are above in the question

Comment: my guess is that the problem is with nginx configuration. Perhaps there is no file served or so? Please add e.g. the sites-available config to ur q. And please check the site of [Bjorn Johansen](https://bjornjohansen.no/enable-http2-on-nginx) and linked configs. The best tutorial I have found on ssl and nginx

Comment: Given this happens with legitimate and self signed certs it is almost definitely a problem with the configs or possibly the keys or the cert not being read right, check `/var/log/nginx/error.log` for any related TLS errors and please include your configs if possible.  (If you see TLS errors in the `error.log` file, please include the error messages you are seeing as well)

Comment: My config files are seperated.  Should I include a link to my git repo?   Dont know if thats allowed or not...

Comment: @Kevin If the configurations are stored on a git repo and the git repo doesn't contain your private keys, then I don't see the harm.  The alternative is to go into each file and copy-paste in the specific `server { }` blocks in their entirety, as we probably won't need more than that.

Comment: Ok, yeah it doesnt contain anything "incriminating" lol.  I've updated the question with the repo.   All configuration is in the /etc folder

Comment: I may rework the config structure... tho may not...   works great so far for non-ssl sites lol

Comment: Sorry...  site specific configurations are in a template in `/usr/bin/templates/site-config-template`   The rest of the nginx configs are in `/etc/nginx/`

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere...   So, with that error, I moved the `listen` directives to the vhost configs.   Now I need to mess with the encryption apparently.  Getting a new error: `The website tried to negotiate an inadequate level of security.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much discussion, and deliberation here, I found what the issue was.

In my main `nginx.conf` I was setting the `listen` directives to both port `80` and `443`

Once I removed them, and added them to the VHost configurations, it started working.